# httpd.conf to allow specific connections for one site but any connection for another

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to setup my apache2 to do the following.

Listen for connections on example.com:80 and answer to any host

Listen to connections on foo.example.com:80 and only answer to localhost

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, don't you edit your httpd.conf file and just add

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

in the virtualhost responsible for example.com:80 and

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

in the one responsible for foo.example.com:80?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I take it it didn't work?